# Validate HTML Textbox

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, validation, html-helper

I have this textbox:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("EffectiveDate", Model.EffectiveDate.HasValue ? Model.EffectiveDate.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") : "", new { @class = "economicTextBox", propertyName = "EffectiveDate", onchange = "parseAndSetDt(this); ", dataType = "Date" })%>
```

I need JS validation help. If the user has the permission, they can enter any date. If the user doesn't, they can only enter the present date, or dates in the future.

Here is a controller method I have that can get if the user has the permission or not.

```
[NoCache]
        public ActionResult HasAdvanced()
        {
            if (Chatham.Web.UI.Extranet.SessionManager.DisplayUser.IsInRole("hasICAdvanced"))
            {
                return Json(
                new
                {
                    value = "true"
                });
            }
            else{
                return Json(
                new
                {
                    value = "false"
                });
            }
        }
```

What would the Js/JQuery look like? I'm soooo stumped.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jquery validation take a look at the [remote](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote) rule.

And it might end up looking like something like this:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    EffectiveDate: {
      required: true,
      remote: "HasAdvanced"
    }
  }
});
```

If you do not want to use an existing framework you could roll your own validation for this one field.

```
$("#EffectiveDate").blur(function(){
  //or $.get
  $.post("HasAdvanced", null, function(data){
    //Handle the json data and update the field display a message, etc......
  }, "json");
});
```

Comment: Where does the HasAdvanced method come into play?

Comment: Does the remote option make the ajax call directly?

Comment: Updated the answer, remote would simply be the location of your HasAdvanced function.

Comment: Can I embed an AJAX call into remote?

Comment: when the form is validated jquery validation will make the remote ajax call for you automatically.  Here is a demo using remote to validate a username http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/

Answer (score 0):

As a sidenote your `HasAdvanced` method could be simplified greatly:

```
return Json(
    new { value = 
        Chatham.Web.UI.Extranet.SessionManager.DisplayUser.IsInRole("hasICAdvanced").ToString() 
    });
```